# need in select 'option' element width smaller than its 'select' with CSS

Tags: html, css

i am facing problem in controlling the **select** menu **option** width its going outside from **select** menu so please see the demo to find out the problem...

CSS

```
select {width:50%;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/P7X8X/1/

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/P7X8X/1/)

Comment: Remove your css. Is this what you expect ? http://jsfiddle.net/P7X8X/3/

Comment: The text is too long, so we can't make it smaller, the right solution is append some ellipsis at the end

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is because you have to much text inside your options.
The text inside your options can't paragraph, what you could do if you wanted your options to stay as they are but fit at a certain size is mess about with your font size.
you can do this by putting a class on your options and setting a font size through that.